# How can I flag items in event viewer from different sites but the same physical server for Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, event-viewer

We are running 2 classic ASP sites (and 2 databases) on the same physical server and we often look at errors in the Event Viewer. The trouble is knowing which site an error was generated from.

Is there a way that I could add a setting for each event to just flag it as to which site it comes from? Either in IIS 7 or a centralized function?

(There is not a lot of code reuse and hardly any error handling, but most pages call the same header & footer.asp code.)

Comment: Have you tried using ElmahASP to log the errors? A coworker implemented this and is really useful to see the errors from all classic asp applications. Worth the read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883071/elmah-errors-and-classic-asp

Comment: That's a really good thought. I've used Elmah in a ASP.Net project once, but not classic ASP.

But I'm still anxious to split those items in Event Viewer.